# MongoDB java slow request after re-election

Tags: java, performance, mongodb

I'm using a MongoDB replica set (with 3 replicas) with a simple Java program (hence using the java mongodb driver). I initialise the driver this way :

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(node0, port),
                new ServerAddress(node1, port),
                new ServerAddress(node2, port)));
```

When I turn down the node0 server (the primary before going down), write queries to the database take some times (5 or 6 secs). I wonder if this is normal, seems weird that it doesn't go hit the new primary node directly.

Any ideas if this is normal ?

**EDIT**

I'm not talking about queries that occur during the election process but queries that are done after a new leader had been elected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does take ~10 seconds or so for the election to take place, and the actual failover to happen. [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/replica-sets/#how-long-does-replica-set-failover-take) is a link to the official documentation:

Comment: The thing is that even after the new leader has been elected, queries are not done directly. Even if the new primary node is primary since 20 minutes